# React Native: как называется шторка с возможностью изменения размера?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Вот похожий плагин - [react-native-actions-sheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-actions-sheet)

Только мне надо, что бы можно было сразу сделать открытым и не было возможности закрыть, только изменять размер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому пригодится, называется такая штука BottomSheet